# Electron 2.0.8 failing to access file in the repository

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron 1.7.9 Windows application that has been working well and I decided to update to the latest version of Electron, 2.0.8. The application needs to copy some template files from the Electron repository to the users file system. With the 1.7.9 application this works fine, however with 2.0.8 the copy fails because the template file cannot be found. The path to the template file relative to the application is:

```
resources\app.asar\Templates\ICC_V8\Startup.S
```

When I debug the application, I am using VS Code, it works just fine.

Any input would be much appreciated,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by moving the templates out of the repository of the Electron app and updating the code to access the templates in the new location.

While this complicates the build of the app, using electron-packager, it does resolve the issue and brings with it the additional benefit of being able to maintain the template files without needing to rebuild the app.